Differential vs derivative in Differential Geometry
In differential geometry one shows that, associated to a smooth map between manifolds $f:M\to N$ there is a linear map $d_pf: T_pM \to T_{f(p)}N$ for each $p\in M$ which is called the differential of $f$ at $p$. My question is: why is it called “differential” and not derivative? I understand the expression in local coordinates is in fact a Jacobian matrix. In my mind “differential” stands for the “change in $f$” and derivative means the rate of change of $f$ compared to the rate of change of the variable. What is the reason for this name?

It's rather random which things are called derivatives and which are called differentials. As far as I can see, the terms derivative and partial derivative are reserved for what you get when you differentiate a function or an $n$-tuple of functions with respect to a variable, parameter, or coordinate. The term differential is used for the linear function or map defined by the linear approximation of a function or map, i.e., the linear map from tangent vectors to directional derivatives. The latter is more abstract and is not defined in terms of coordinates.

I concur that there isn't a perfectly consistent rule here. For example the exterior derivative of a real-valued function is its differential (in fact perhaps it should just be called the exterior differential).

Consider the case when $f$ is a smooth function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$. In a calculus course, one would one call the tangent map a differential like "$dx$" or a derivative like $"\frac{d}{dx}"$?
I think a large part of this fact that the tangent map (aka pushforward) is called the differential is the above fact that it corresponds with the exterior derivative of a function in the appropriate context.
